# Java: a null pointer exception after a null-check

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Would anyone be so kind as to help me to understand how can I get a null pointer exception here?

```
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityCollection = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<UserRole> userRoleCollection = user.getUserRoleList();
        if(userRoleCollection != null) {
            if (userDetailsService.getAuthorities(userRoleCollection) != null) {
            // ^^^ it occurs at the line above ^^^
                grantedAuthorityCollection.addAll(userDetailsService.getAuthorities(userRoleCollection));
            }
        }
        return grantedAuthorityCollection;
    }
```

Here's what I get at run-time:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at ua.tucha.passpass.web.security.UserDetails.getAuthorities(UserDetails.java:31)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.createSuccessAuthentication(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:225)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.createSuccessAuthentication(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:197)
    ...
```

How can it be? I've just made sure if there's not `null` in `userRoleCollection`, the next instruction wouldn't have been executed if there was `null`, would it?

Thank you very much in advance for your kind help.

Comment: You've not checked whether `userDetailsService` is null.

Comment: Damn! Thank you, it really was `null`, I forgot to make it static!